# Ways to avoid Question Block

Tags: support

I have been getting a warning as follows:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more. For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question? Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity

Now from previous posts on the site that I checked here I know this is because I have only asked few questions uptil now and they were either down-voted, did not get enough views or were answered but without any upvotes. So I decided that maybe if I contributed by answering some questions then the warning would go away, however that doesn't seem to be the case. So is the only way to make this warning go away is ask better questions and improve my previous questions? I have answered questions with relevant info and most of my answers were accepted and even upvoted (only one or two upvotes uptil now on most) recently. So does contributing better and correct answers help me avoid the warning or is it specifically just linked to questions I ask?

Comment: One problem I see in your questions is that you never include enough code in the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BSMP thanx for the advice I'll try to add more relevant code in questions I ask next. The article Oded mentions states to only add minimal code needed to replicate the issue. I'll try to keep that balance.

Comment: @hunters30  BSMP never said to include a code dump, he said you don't include enough to reproduce your issue (in other terms, you don't have a minimal example). There's no balance to be kept here. The code in your question must be enough to reproduce your issue. One thing as well is that possibly you don't research enough. Coming to meta asking that question, then saying the article Oded linked solved your issue, when the article was linked in the warning you got, possibly means you don't fully research before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is the only way to make this warning go away is ask better questions and improve my previous questions?

Essentially, yes.

Answering well and asking well are two very different skills.

I suggest reading the help center article on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and following those guidelines. Research before asking and share the research in the question.

Comment: Ok cool read through it all and will keep it in mind next time I ask. So improving the question quality is very essential and the only way that I can resolve this. Thanks