# Facing a "Question Block" - How do I proceed without making things worse?

Tags: discussion

**It looks like I'm facing a "Question Ban".**

It appears to be a warning only, at this time, because this warning appears at the top of the "New Question Form", but the form is in fact there with a "Post Your Question" button at the bottom.

I haven't actually tried to post a new question because I'd like to figure out what's wrong with my existing questions, and fix that before I do get myself banned.

However.....

I see instances where questions are closed (or used as the basis for blocking)  because it is "*too opinionated*", "*low quality*", "*not helpful*", "*significantly downvoted*", or "*zero voted*".

The problem is all these things are purely subjective given that SO's position is that "*The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed*".

If you cannot tell me exactly which question is offensive, or in what way it is offensive, then you can scarcely blame me for not fixing it.  Combine that with the fact that one of the criteria is "*significantly down voted*" or "*zero voted*" questions, which is completely out of the hands of the questioner.

And "*too opinionated*" is, uhm, an opinion.

I cannot make you upvote or downvote anything, and in fact, **this policy will actually lend official sanction to "trolling".**

On top of that, people other than the author can modify my question, and add or remove tags.  The question becomes a community submission, and no longer my submission, yet I get the blame for the downvotes it may or may not receive?  If SO allows other users to modify my question, then I will no longer accept responsibility for the quality or lack thereof.

I have gone over my past questions, and to be frank, I do not see a problem with any of them. There is only one which might fit the "significantly downvoted" category.  It received an astonishing 4 downvotes!  And I rather agree with that downvote.  Not because I didn't ask a good question but because the comments went off in all directions and became a meandering discussion instead of leading to a clear answer (which, I did get, btw).

There are a number of questions that received zero votes, but how again is that my fault?  I'm not in control of your mouse.  I can't MAKE you vote for me, so what is the point of penalising the questioner because no one wants to, or is able to answer?

As to the quality of my posts, I tend to be a bit more elaborate in my question asking because I want to err on the side of caution and give more information rather than not enough.  I want the audience to have as much information as they need to give a reasonable answer.  And, to SO's credit, I usually do get a good answer that is informative and helpful.

I actually ran into a guy who suggested that "*if you aren't up to our 'level' in your developer skills, then maybe Stack Overflow isn't for you*".  Seriously?

While I might not be an expert in all things, I am at least not a novice in the categories of my questions.  By the time I'm reduced to resorting to StackOverflow for help, it's probably not a trivial thing.  I sometimes do not know the technical nomenclature for what I'm trying to accomplish, so I give an example of what I am trying to accomplish and trust that the more advanced users in the community will think, "*Aha!  What you are trying to do is called xyz, and here is how it works.*"

Notice I didn't say "*here's how to do it*".  I said "*here's how it works*".

Might I just remind us that I don't come to SO just to "get an answer".  I come here **TO LEARN**.

And my questions are largely targeted at LEARNING, not just getting a piece of cut-n-paste code to put in my program.  I'm not a cut-n-paste coder.  I want to UNDERSTAND what I am doing, not just "get it done".  And SO's strict policy of "We want questions that can be answered" actually promotes the cut-n-paste coder, not the practicioner or the serious developer.

I may just be at odds with the philosophical underpinnings of the StackOverflow team, but I'm much more helped and advanced by meaningful *discussions*, than merely answers to questions.  But, I understand what they are trying to build, and I do not have any complaint about that.

I am a completely novice SO User, so take this with a grain of salt, but I think we are in danger of turning into cut-n-paste code repository instead of a learning center.

All that being said, here's my question: If SO will not reveal the reasons a question is substandard, and will not tell me exactly which questions are the problem, then how exactly do I go about fixing this "*You are about to be blocked*" problem?

*[I have already been here:
[Ways to avoid Question Block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306205/ways-to-avoid-question-block),
[How can I understand why am I receiving a warning that I could be blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked),
and here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]*

Comment: For a slightly different perspective, can you read [Why is it so hard to get started?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)? On a different tangent: did you delete some of your questions? They still count against you ... (BTW "opininiated" is just for broad "what is the best way to do x?" questions.)

Comment: Do you know [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for an education. This is not a classroom.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you do not see the issue with your questions posted. For the most part they are simply requesting that the community do some research for you by solving your current debugging dilemma. I will not action any of your questions because I found them as a result of looking your profile and in my opinion that is unfair. However, had I seen them in the wild there are several issues that would have been addressed. Several of them are subject to closure.

Comment: Thank you Travis for perfectly demonstrating my point.

Comment: Thank you,  Travis J, PetahChristian, Luke, HaveNoDisplayName, and Alexei Levenkov, for marking my question as a duplicate without saying which post it is a duplicate of.  And, "*Why is it so hard to get started*" addresses none of the points of my OP, but instead only covers the same points in the posts in my "Already been here" disclaimer at the bottom of my OP.  But thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: Here's a good example of the only other question I've EVER asked that got downvoted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958039/how-to-determine-what-javascript-object-has-been-returned.

I ask a straightforward question: "How do I examine an object?", and I got a very straightforward answer: "Use typeof", which I promptly marked as the answer and ran away giggling with my newfound toy.  Downvote?  What?

Comment: What I think is really going on here is a certain level of "elitism" in the ranks.  And I'm betting some of you were just *waiting* for me to say that.  ;-) heh.  BTW - this is "meta", which I am told is the place to have DISCUSSIONS.  So, forgive me if I'm doing that.

Comment: You're not discussing, you're pissed and ranting.  It's understandable, but don't pee on our legs and tell us it's raining.  Simple questions are like russian roulette--you might get lots of rep, or you might end up in a vegetative state.  I, too, recently had some issues involving basic javascript.  I didn't bother asking about them, as I knew it wouldn't be a real solution to my real issue--I lacked some basic knowledge of how JS works.  So I bought the two top javascript books on Amazon. Read one in three hours, the other waits for me. You should try it too.

Comment: Thanks, Will. That's why I'm on meta. That's what its for.

Comment: Hey, look.  Someone was nice enough to add a "*this is a duplicate of this question*".  I checked it out, and it is kinda helpful.  However, I still wonder.  I've never deleted ANY questions, that I can think of, and of the 21 questions I have asked, only two (just 2) of them have received ANY downvotes.  And the sum total of all downvotes is exactly -6.  Not really a waterfall of downvotes.  Well, I have a new question to ask, so let's see if I can do this one right!  ;-)  Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Comment: I went back and had a look, and it turns out I did delete one question.  Last month.  It was a question about hardware, and I was told SO was not a place for hardware questions.  So, I agreed and deleted the question.  So, I do have that one deletion. EDIT: **I** didn't delete it, it was "deleted by the community".  Nice to know I can be penalised for someone else's actions.  heh.

Comment: Additional question: Can the way I respond to proposed answers, or can my comments to others affect my "score?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets do a bit of a self-introspection here. We know what can trip a question ban:

- Large number of downvoted questions
- Large number of deleted questions
- Anonymous votes do factor into the equation, but *slightly*.

I only see you having two questions which are scored -1 or lower, so the only other issue could be the number of questions you've deleted (and a moderator would be able to go back deeper to figure this out).

If you delete a lot of questions, then it's seen as an abuse against the system; you're asking a question, people look at it, some may start mulling it over, and then all of a sudden it's gone, which burns other people's volunteer time.

Be sure you haven't deleted large swathes of questions recently.

In general, to be sure your questions are received warmly:

- State your question as clearly as you can
- Provide any resources that are necessary to answer the question, such as a complete code snippet
- Provide context into the problem, or express if there are any constraints placed on you as a result of your question
- Be clear about what it is you're trying to accomplish; don't just say "it doesn't work" or "I don't understand" since those are fundamentally difficult to answer.

Lastly:

> Might I just remind us that I don't come to SO just to "get an answer". I come here TO LEARN.

I'm glad to hear that.  That's how I got started here too.  But, just because you're here to learn doesn't mean that your question quality can be lax.  You have to ask [good, on-topic questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and it may behoove you to do a wee bit more research on a question you have to be sure that you've exhausted all of your possible avenues. [For context, read this question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1079354)

Comment: I'm stymied on this one.  I haven't deleted ANY questions (that I can recall, anyway).  And, as you have pointed out, I don't have many negative votes with the exception of that one that got a whopping 4 downvotes, which even I agree with.  And I think I can state with confidence that I am not a grammar lackey, or a spelling twit, but I am someone who develop a succinct thought.

Comment: What I DO think may be part of the problem is that while I do know what I am trying to accomplish, I often do not know the technical terminology for it, and instead I end up trying to ask the question by describing the question, not simply asking it.

Comment: Makoto, yes, I had read that one.  It was one of the recommended "go here first" suggestions that popped up while I was creating this entry.  When I ask a question, it is because I have run out of alternatives.  But SO has no idea what steps I've taken before resorting to posting a question.  SO is a LAST RESORT for me.  And that's a good thing.

Comment: Here's a good example.  Compare this question: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object"

with my *uber-downvoted* (ie, **4** whole downvotes) question:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958039/how-to-determine-what-javascript-object-has-been-returned"

Almost the same question.  Theirs with grammatical errors (that someone actually asked to be fixed), and ambiguous wording.  600+ upvotes.

Me?  I lost four reputation points for the same question.  The truth is, SO runs on group psychology.  It's as much luck as anything how you are received.

Comment: I am NOT complaining, however.  In spite of the inherent, and unavoidable weakness of an "automated" algorithm-driven, public audience moderation paradigm, SO is nonetheless a powerful resource and a great help to me.

Answer (score 6):

SO does not disclose how exactly the community's response to your contributions (upvotes, downvotes, closing, deleting, flagging), and your actions themselves are combined into their estimation whether you are a confirmed lost cause, potentially redeemable if given another choice, a blank slate, or a force of good.
That's by design, to reduce *gaming the system*.

Which in no way means that the signals used are in any way ambiguous about that:

Negative contributions get downvoted, closed, and deleted. At least if (enough) people who care notice them.
Positive contributions get upvoted. Though especially new users often suffer from impaired target-differentiating.

Now why *exactly* a *specific* contribution by you got that *specific* response, we can only speculate, but most cases are blatantly obvious with a bit of thought.
The [help-center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help), the [tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour) and the voting-tooltips and of course the big banners when a question get closed or a post deleted should help.